# Change background of Sign-in page of Gitlab

Tags: user-interface, gitlab

We are using **slef hosted Gitlab-ee**  latest version. We customized Sign-in page but background color of it is white and quite boaring. Is there any possibility to add picture or another color to Gitlab Sign-in page?

Comment: If you fork Gitlab-EE yourself you can alter whatever you want, but by default there is nothing you can configure.

Comment: forking Gitlab-ee? I done forking project but never forked gitlab-ee. What is meant by `fork Gitlab-EE`

Comment: On https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee -> Fork
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/fork-project.html

Comment: how does `forking a project` will help me to change Sign in page UI?

Comment: You can alter anything you want, including the UI appearance, customize it as much as you like.

Comment: We can change `Sign-in Page` by `forking` a project? Is there any reference doc or link?

Comment: I guess some file on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/app/views/ will refer to the login page.

Anyway, keep in mind that having your own Gitlab project would mean maintaining it, or apply the same changes to newer versions, which can be tedious.